# why does my pointer points to null when i have reinitialized it from root

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers

I will try to keep it as simple as possible.

Basically, I am working with graphs and writing Kruskal's Algorithm for a minimum spanning tree. I have made a class of forest, each forest node contains a link list whose head represents a vertice of the graph, and ahead connected nodes contain the vertices that the main head vertice is connected to, and the next forest node contains the next vertice of the graph, and the link list in that forest node contains the vertices that the specific vertice is connected to.

My code up until now is 400 lines. I will share a snippet that contains the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node* right;
    node()
    {
        data = 0;
        right = NULL;
    }
    ~node()
    {
        cout << data << " node has been destroyed " << endl;
    }
};


class forest
{
public:
    node* vertices;
    int weight;
    forest* next;
    forest()
    {
        vertices = NULL;
        weight = 0;
        next = NULL;
    }
    ~forest()
    {
        cout << vertices->data << " vertice has been destroyed " << endl;
    }
};

class que
{
public:
    int root;
    int connected;
    int weight;
    int set_no;         // for checking of disjoint sets
    que* next;
    que()
    {
        root = 0;
        connected = 0;
        weight = 0;
        set_no = 0;
        next = NULL;
    }
    ~que()
    {
        cout << "edge with root " << root << " connected to " << connected << " has been dequed " << endl;

    }
};
que* priority_dq(que*& front)
{
    que* move = front;
    que* link = front;
    que* required = new que;
    required = move;
    while (move->next != NULL)
    {
        if (required->weight > move->next->weight)
        {
            link = move;
            required = move->next;
        }
        move = move->next;
    }
    if (link == front)
    {
        front = front->next;
        link->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        link->next = required->next;
    }
    return required;
}

void make_spanning_tree(forest*& root, que*& front, int count)
{
    que* use;
    forest* sets = new forest; // we using forest here bcz the data structure of its members is according to the dynamically changing disjoint set structure we need 
    int set_no = 1;           // each forest node 's vertices will contain 1 set's members
    node* move = new node;
    forest* iterate;
    //forest* start ;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        iterate = sets;
        use = priority_dq(front);
        if (iterate->vertices->data == 0)
        {
            iterate->vertices->data = use->root;
            node* add = new node;
            add->data = use->connected;
            iterate->vertices->right = add;
        }
        else
        {
            int* r_count = new int[set_no], * c_count = new int[set_no];
            int new_r = 1, new_c = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < set_no; j++)
            {
                r_count[j] = 0;
                c_count[j] = 0;
                move = iterate->vertices;
                while (move != NULL)
                {
                    if (use->root == move->data)
                    {
                        r_count[j] = 1;
                        new_r = 0;
                    }
                    if (use->connected == move->data)
                    {
                        c_count[j] = 1;
                        new_c = 0;
                    }
                    move = move->right;
                }
                iterate = iterate->next;
            }
        }
    }
    iterate = sets;
    while (iterate != NULL)
    {
        move = iterate->vertices;
        while (move != NULL)
        {
            cout << move->data << " ";
            move = move->right;
        }
        cout << endl;
        iterate = iterate->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    forest* root = new forest;
    forest* temp = root;

    int a;
    cout << "enter the vertices for the graph and enter -1 to stop" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    while (a != -1)
    {
        temp = root;
        if (temp->vertices == NULL)
        {
            node* join = new node;
            join->data = a;
            temp->vertices = join;
        }
        else
        {
            while (temp->next != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            node* join = new node;
            join->data = a;
            forest* add = new forest;
            add->vertices = join;
            temp->next = add;
        }
        cin >> a;
    }
    que* front = new que;
    int count = 1, from, to;
    cout << "Now enter the edges(atleast 3) present in the graph and their respective weights.To stop enter -1 " << endl;
    cout << "what is the root of edge no " << count << " ? ";
    cin >> from;
    while (from != -1)
    {
        forest* check;
        check = root;
        int is_vertice = 0;
        while (check != NULL)
        {
            if (check->vertices->data == from)
            {
                is_vertice = 1;
            }
            check = check->next;
        }
        if (is_vertice == 0)
        {
            cout << "sorry vertice is not present in  graph, try an exsisting one " << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nwhat is it connected to ? ";
            cin >> to;
            while (to != -1)
            {
                check = root;
                is_vertice = 0;
                while (check != NULL)
                {
                    if (check->vertices->data == to)
                    {
                        is_vertice = 1;
                    }
                    check = check->next;
                }
                if (is_vertice == 0)
                {
                    cout << "sorry vertice is not present in  graph, try an exsisting one or enter -1 to stop" << endl;
                    cin >> to;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (front->root == 0)
                    {
                        front->root = from;
                        front->connected = to;
                        cout << "enter the weight of this edge" << endl;
                        cin >> to;
                        front->weight = to;
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        que* add = new que;
                        add->root = from;
                        add->connected = to;
                        cout << "enter the weight of this edge" << endl;
                        cin >> to;
                        add->weight = to;
                        add->next = front;
                        front = add;
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "enter next vertice root for edge no " << count << " or enter -1 to stop " << endl;
        cin >> from;

    }
    que* move = front;
    cout << "EDGES: " << endl;
    while (move != NULL)
    {
        cout << "from " << move->root << " to " << move->connected << " ,weight: " << move->weight << endl;
        move = move->next;
    }
    move = priority_dq(front);
    cout <<endl<< "minimum weight edge" << endl;
    cout << endl << "from " << move->root << " to " << move->connected << " ,weight: " << move->weight << endl << endl;
    move = front;
    cout << endl << "que afterwards" << endl;
    while (move != NULL)
    {
        cout << "from " << move->root << " to " << move->connected << " ,weight: " << move->weight << endl;
        move = move->next;
    }
    cout << endl << "SETS:" << endl;
    make_spanning_tree(root, front, count);
}
```

The main problem to focus on here is that in my make spanning tree function, the 1st `for` loop in the 1st `if` check, where I'm reading `iterate->vertice->data`, tells me `iterate` contains same null value as the below move did.  So, this means my first iteration passed okay with the 1st `if` used, then in the 2nd loop iteration, my `else` part was used in which move pointed to null, and now in the third (most probably) it says `iterate->vertices` has the same value null as the move did. That doesn't make any sense, because I'm re-initializing `iterate` with `sets`, which is the root or head which can never be null because I didn't delete my main object, and I want my checks to be read again from the start every time.

I can't understand why it still points to the below null from the last iteration.

Comment: What I would do: Run the code in whatever debugging too came with my development tools and keep an eye on the variables of interest. When they change to an unexpected value I scrutinize the path that lead up to it, possibly running the program over and over gathering more details until I understood the problem and could solve it.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even compile. For example, you're using set_no when it's not in scope. Try following the guide at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask especially https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i am using visual studios and when i run the debuuging tool it tells me the exact place where the problem is that is iterate->vertices reading part

Comment: oh  i didnt give the full code because it was pretty long but i have now shared a smaller part that complies

Comment: That's still a lot of code. You haven't finished debugging yet, sorry.

Comment: you just only have to focus on the make spanning tree function where the problem is rest is there so that the code can compile which i checked it does on my visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your program and it throws exception in first `iterate->vertices->data` in `make_spanning_tree`, saying that `iterate->vertices` is `nullptr`.

You said you're re-initializing `iterate` with `sets` which is the root or head, but it seems that `sets` is `new forest` which has `nullptr` as `vertices`, not root.

Comment: by root i mean the first fixed starting point of my forest objects which are linked like link list by the next member in their class.

Comment: oh God ur right.. i see what i was missing out on . Thank you